# How applications usually store their data (in java)?

Tags: java, sql, json, database

I'm trying to write a program in Java for personal accounting. My initial plan was for user to log in, and the program would look him up in a text file and let him in. Then there would be a JTable which would load all his transactions (from a txt) and show them. He would then add new ones or edit/delete ones already there. The program would find the line and change it.

But as I started the implementation, I quickly found out that the manipulation with the text file was very exhausting.

I thought about SQL database, or JSON files, but I don't know, if that's a good idea, and where to start. I'm rather new to java, so even opening a text file was a bit of a hassle for me.

Any thoughts?

Thank you.

Comment: Storing and manipulating data is exactly what a database is for. There are an enormous number of implementations, but a simple one to start with would be something like [Apache Derby](https://db.apache.org/derby/).

Comment: depends on your application need. If very small scale application with limited transactions then derby or similar would work. If you need greater concurrency and high volume data then go for mysql or similar. If your design is more towards document store then you can use no-sql DBs like mongo, couchbase or even openstack.

Comment: To be fair/honest, and not mean, if just opening a text file is a hassle working with JSON or a DB is likely going to be hell on wheels.

Comment: @aryn.galadar Derby looks promising. I'll try to learn bout it some more. And it will probably be  very small database. Just rows of text, like description, date, amount of money etc. I've got some experience with SQL, so maybe it won't be that bad. It's just that I haven't tried to use it in a program before. Just requesting data from databases and such.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils What I mean't was, it wasn't very intuitive. I had to write tonns of algorithms just to get to the data, and I thoth there must be a better way. Whenever I finished a method that did something very basic with the file, I always thought, "why didn't they include something like this in the libraries".

Comment: Gotcha, then maybe [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/index.htm) could be of service for targeting a db from a Java program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is for personal accounting and likely small, you could think of it like any document editing program (Notepad, Word, Excel, ...), meaning:

- No login. Each person will have a separate file chosen when you start program.
- Load entire file into memory.
- Nothing is saved until user clicks "Save" (unless you want some auto-recovery logic in case of program/machine crash).

That means that there are only two operations on the file (Load and Save), and both should be fairly simple.

Advantage: Simple and very fast.

Limitation: Memory constraint if file grows very large, and potential for data loss if auto-recovery/auto-save is not implemented.

Comment: That's interesting. So I should use the text files? I was thinking I would try the Apache Derby and do it in SQL. I'm sure it would be a good experience learning to connect a database to my program and I could also use it in other projects later. So maybe this project is ideal for text files but I was thinking about practising for harder ones you know.

Comment: Sure, learning to do SQL from Java is *very* valuable knowledge, so I'd go with that if you have the extra time to learn. This answer was just a suggestion for keeping it simple, which is very valid if you have time constraints, and may or may not be a better choice depending on desired functionality of the application.

Comment: I think I'll try to do both, the simple version and the version with the database. Thanks :)